# What does it take to sync a contact/calendars web app with mobile devices?

Tags: android, ios, windows-phone-7, mobile, synchronization

I have been developing a web application in PHP that provides contact and calendar management.  This application needs to sync its contact and calendar data with mobile devices (specifically Android, Apple, and Windows phones).

I have no experience in mobile development, so I am mostly looking for guidance.  It is difficult to know what to even search for because of this lack of experience.  I am mostly looking to know what is possible and what is not.

The **overall goal** is to be able to edit contact/calendar data from anywhere, whether that be from the web application itself or a mobile device.  These changes will then be reflected no matter what tool you are using to view it.  A very loose comparison is an IMAP server.  One central data source where any app can hop in and view/manage e-mails.

My web application can currently handle HTTP requests using XML data.  So it can send out data and have data POSTed into it.

This is where my knowledge ends.  I have little insight as to what would be required of the device itself to be able to sync.  If a user adds contacts to a mobile device's default contact/calendar application, how can it be told to sync with my web application?  Does this mean developing an app for each mobile device in order to act as a medium between my application and the mobile device's default contact/calendar data?

Is it possible to access the internal contact/calendar data of a mobile device?  Can that data be pushed to an external server or be modified by that same server?  What is required on the web application's side?  The mobile device's side?

These are the sort of questions I am looking to be answered.  There might be questions that I haven't even thought of that I would also love to be discussed.  If my question is too general, please specify anything to be clarified.

Answer (score 0):

In case of iphone you have to write your own app. I would recommend to use a database (sql) on your server, then every time the application opens you can check if there are new entries on the server and load them if needed.

I think it will take you some time to get the basic knowledge about ios programming but it isn't a hard job at all.

Things you should check:

- requests
- uitableview(/delegate)
- Event kit

There are good tutorials to learn this stuff.

One good site: 
http://www.raywenderlich.com/

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  Just to be sure, using those topics, I will be able to pull data directly from the iOS contacts address book and the calendar?  And then write to it as well?  Also, is the process similar (or the same) for an iPad?  And for OSX's address book and iCal programs, I am assuming another app would need to be written?